# Maximize a group of windows at the same time on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, tabs

On Windows 10, is there a way to minimize/maximize a group of windows (from the same app) at the same time, with one single click on one of the windows/tasks in the Windows taskbar for example?

I would like to display 2 Chrome windows side by side when I focus (minimize/maximize) on one of them.

Or have 2 Chrome tabs side by side in the same Chrome window.

Comment: WinKey+left arrow to snap chrome to left side of screen ----
    Ctrl+N to open a new Chrome Window ---
    WinKey+right arrow to snap new chrome instance to right side of screen --- or something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-resize-split-screen-l/bkpenclhmiealbebdopglffmfdiilejc or one of these https://www.groovypost.com/howto/view-multiple-google-chrome-tabs-split-screen/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know the Windows snap feature, this is part of what i want, however it doesn't display the 2 Chrome windows at the same time after I'm using other apps/windows, I have to focus/click again on the 2 Chrome windows, even with the tab resize add-on.

Comment: This is not possible with what Windows natively offers. There may be third-party apps that do this, but I'm unaware of such apps. The only thing you can do instead is use Virtual Desktops. If you place all chrome windows on one virtual desktop, they all show/hide at the same time when switching from/to a desktop.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for this workaround, I might try that.